# shap.summary bar plot and normal plot lists different features on y_axis

Tags: python-3.x, shap

After running a `random forest` classifier and generating the `shap` plots, I get two different values showing up on the y-axis.  Is this designed and I have to sort the features before hand or is there a bug in the code?

Here is a snippet of the code that I am using:

```
import shap

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(clf)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

[image]

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test)
```

[image]

Is there an explanation as to why the two graphs gives different values on the y-axis?  Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest looking at it class by class. That is, you can plot the shap_summary plot only for class 9 for example and see if the order of that matches the order you see in the bar plot